# Await doesn't wait for the function to end + Node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm new to Node.js and was trying to get a lease from azure blob.

```
const leaseID = await acquireLease(container,blobName);
const result = await download(blob);
```

and acquireLease method is

```
const acquireLease = async function(container,blobName){

    var leaseID;

        blobService.acquireLease(container,blobName ,function(error,result,response){

            if(!error) {

                // Got lease

                 leaseID =  result.id;
              }

        })

        return(leaseID);
}

exports.acquireLease = acquireLease;
```

but before the acquireLease method gets completed and leaseID is got, the next main method

```
const result = await download(blob);
```

gets executed.
I tried promises but couldn't succeed.

```
const acquireLease = async function(container,blobName){

    var leaseID;

    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{

        blobSvc.acquireLease(container,blobName ,function(error,result,response){

            if(!error) {

                // Got lease

                 leaseID =  result.id;
              }

        })

        resolve(leaseID);

    })

}

exports.acquireLease = acquireLease;
```

Any suggestions or help appreciated.

Comment: You're really snatching defeat from the jaws of victory with the promise attempt - you need to resolve the value _where you get it_, not in the same place you didn't have access to it in the synchronous version (and ideally, also reject if there's an error).

Comment: Hi @jonrsharpe , thanks for reaching out. I'm sorry but I didn't understand 'where you get it'.  can you please elaborate?. thank you.

Comment: The promise should be resolved inside the `if` statement, I mean inside the `acquireLease` callback because only in that place you have the correct value of `leaseID`.

Comment: No problem =) =)

Comment: I.e. where you say `Got lease`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were *really* close with your Promise version! You just need to call `resolve` and `reject` at the right times.

Presumably, if `error` is truthy, then you should reject.  Otherwise, it's safe to assume your result is valid and you can resolve the promise with `result.id`.  There is no need for a `leaseID` variable.  Also, if the function just returns a Promise, there's no need to mark it async.

```
const acquireLease = function (container, blobName) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        blobSvc.acquireLease(container, blobName, function (error, result, response) {
            if (error) {
                reject(error)
            } else {
                resolve(result.id)
            }
        })
    })
}

exports.acquireLease = acquireLease;
```